# Django: use of __lte for automatic publication of a post

Tags: django, django-views, django-filter

I'm developing a blog and I'm using this filter for put online the posts automatically:

```
geopost_filter = GeoPost.objects.filter(draft=False, publishing_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

This filter run in local but doesn't run in production. For put online the post that pass from "it will be published in future" to "it is now online" I must restart the server in production.

Why happen this?

I can change the post's status using the draft field without problem, both in local than in production. But it seams not possible to publish automatically a post if it is marked as future post.

**EDIT after request from Willem Van Onsem**

I use this filter into a view and into an api view.

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.db.models.functions import Now
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render
from .models import GeoPost, GeoTag

geopost_filter = GeoPost.objects.filter(
    draft=False,
    publishing_date__lte=Now()
)

def geotag_single(request, slug_tag):
    geotag = get_object_or_404(GeoTag, slug_tag=slug_tag)
    geopost_full = geopost_filter.filter(tags=geotag)

    paginator = Paginator(geopost_full, 10)
    page = request.GET.get("pagina")
    geopost_list = paginator.get_page(page)

    context = {
            "tag": geotag,
            "post_list": geopost_list,
            }

    return render(request, 'geoblog/single_tag.html', context)
```

*apiviews*

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from geoblog.models import GeoPost
from geoblog.views import geopost_filter

@api_view(["GET"])
def geoblogPost_apiview(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.user.is_staff:
            objects = GeoPost.objects.all()
        else:
            objects = geopost_filter
        serializer = GeoPostSerializer(objects, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

GeoPost is a model that use the PontField together the classical fields of a blog post like title and contents. This is an example:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

GeoPost(models.Model):
    geom = models.PointField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    publishing_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now,
        )
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=70,
        unique=True,
    )
    contents = models.TextField()
    draft = models.BooleanField()
```

Maybe the problem is in `publishing_date` because I use `timezone.now`?

Comment: Do you "rerun" the query each time? Or did you define it somewhere and reuse the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely you defined the query once, and reuse it multiple times. As a result the `timezone.now` is *not* updated, and thus the "new" `GeoPost`s do not get published.

You can however make use of the database time with a [**`Now`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#now):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now

geopost_filter = GeoPost.objects.filter(
    draft=False, publishing_date__lte=Now()
)
```

Here `Now` is not converted to the time when you *construct* the queryset, it uses the time at the database, so you can reuse this queryset.

Another problem is that you make use of a global variable, and thus the results get cached. This means that after making one query, the query is not done again. You can force requerying, for example with `.all()`:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def geoblogPost_apiview(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.user.is_staff:
            objects = GeoPost.objects.all()
        else:
            objects = geopost_filter.all()
        serializer = GeoPostSerializer(objects, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Probably it is a mine misunderstanding. I thought that `timezone.now()` it was similar to `Now()`.  The strange thing it's that I've this problem only in production. Why doesn't happen when I'm developing on localhost?

Comment: @MassimilianoMoraca: likely because the server restarts each time you make a change. But no, `timezone.now()` and `Now()` are not similar in the sense that `timezone.now()` results in a `datetime` object (so once called, it remains the same value).

Comment: Ok, I understand, thank you for the explanation. I've used your indication and on localhost it runs. The next future post will pass online next Tuesday and hope that all runs fine. Someone suggest me to use Celery but I know that it is usefull for complex projects and this blog is a simple blog..

Comment: Unfortunatly today it was possible to see the new post only after server restart

Comment: @MassimilianoMoraca: but you did ***not*** use `timezone.now()`, right?

Comment: @MassimilianoMoraca: but the import references are important. Furthermore it might be useful to share the *view* where you use this, can you edit the question? If you for example *materialize* the queryset, then regardless how you define it, it will not work, since then you load the objects in memory, and always use that memory (and thus do not make new queries).

Comment: Ok, I edit the question as soon as possible. Thank you for the support and the patience

Comment: Thank you! Now it really run :)